# When we say that $dX_t= f(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t$ does this equality hold almost surely?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space.

- If $(X_t)$ satisfy $$dX_t=f(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t,$$
  does it mean that $dX_t=f(X_t)dt+\sigma (X_t)dB_t$ almost surely ? i.e. that $$\mathbb P\{X_t=X_0+\int_0^tf(X_t)dt+\int_0^t \sigma (X_t)dB_t \}=1 \ \ ?$$
- Same, if $X$ is a random variable, when we say that $Y=f(X)$, does it mean that $\mathbb P\{Y=f(X)\}=1$ or it's really $Y(\omega )=f(X(\omega ))$ for all $\omega $ ?

Comment: First question: "does it mean that ..." No. "i.e. that ..." Usually, yes. Second question:  "does it mean that ..." usually, no, but rather the latter meaning. However, it depends on the context; in some contexts (conditional expectations, spaces $L^p$ etc) the former meaning is standard.

Comment: @zhoraster: Thank you but for the answer of the first question, you say yes and no for the same thing, no ?

Comment: No. What is $dX_t$?